# c++ - regarding memory leak - new

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am studying some c++ and have a simple question regarding memory leaks. Everything that creates with new should also be deleted right?

So for example, this code should have memory leaks:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node* next;
};

bool insert(Node** head, int val)
{
    Node* temp = *head;

    if((*head)->data == val)
        return false;

    if(*head == nullptr || (*head)->data > val)
    {
        Node* new_node = new Node();

        new_node->next = *head;
        new_node->data = val;

        *head = new_node;

        return true;
    }

    while(temp->next != nullptr && temp->next->data <= val)
    {
        temp = temp->next;

        if(temp->data == val)
            return false;
    }

    //Sätt in ny nod
    Node* new_node = new Node{val, temp->next};
    temp->next = new_node;

    return true;
}

void print(Node** head)
{
    Node* temp = *head;

    while(temp != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << temp->data << ' ';
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node* head = new Node{0, nullptr};
    Node* another = new Node{1, nullptr};
    head->next = another;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        if(insert(&head, i % 5))
            std::cout << "Inserted " << i % 5 << " into the list.\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Could not insert " << i % 5 << " into the list.\n";

    std::cout << "List is: ";
    print(&head);

    insert(&head, -1);
    insert(&head, 22);
    insert(&head, 13);
    insert(&head, 11);
    insert(&head, 19);

    std::cout << "\nList is: ";
    print(&head);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand memory leaks, so do i have to loop through the structs and remove everything or is it enough to only delete "head" and "another" in order to prevent this code from having memory leaks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since I can't spot a single `delete`, yes. What you're actually asking about? You just wanted a confirmation?

Comment: Well as you can see the struct holds a pointer to the same structor. And as you can see I create a new struct and point it to the old struct. So if i only delete the head and another in the main function, that should remove all of the other struct it is pointing to as well right? Or do i have to loop through it and delete all of the newly created structs?

Comment: You have to loop through it and delete all of the newly created structs. In C++ you _have_ to delete all objects you create.

Comment: Thank you mate, that cleared up everything

Comment: @basdbfnsa _"Everything that creates with new should also be deleted right?"_ I was referring specifically to this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, deleting "head" and "another" is not enough.  In this code, every insert() call allocates a new node, so if you were going do add proper cleanup code, you would want to walk your linked list and delete *every* node in the list.  Since a node just holds a pointer to another node, it has no information about who owns the node and won't delete it automatically.

For this reason you would generally want to create an actual "list" structure that would manage the allocation and then destroy the nodes in it's destructor.